# how do i compare types in c++?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to divide two integers, and if the output is not an integer, it doesn't continue. for some reason this refuses to work no matter what i try.

```
    int numeratorOutput{};
    int denominatorOutput{};

    for (int i{ 2 }; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        auto test = numerator / i;
        auto test2 = denominator / i;

        if (typeid(test) == typeid(int) && typeid(test2) == typeid(int))
        {
            cout << i << '\n';
            cout << "yes\n\n";

            numeratorOutput = numerator / i;
            denominatorOutput = denominator / i;

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "no\n";
        }
    }
```

i tried typeid, sizeof, is_same, etc.; but it let to no avail

Comment: If you divide two integers, the result is **always** an integer.

Comment: Types in C++ are fixed at compile time.  Whatever it is you're trying to  do, `typeid` is not the answer.

Comment: `auto` does not change the type at runtime. It determines the type at compile time

Comment: @chapel1337 I think what you try to ask is, how to check if division result is integer in the mathematical sense. That's operator '%': `if (a%b == 0)` means that `a` is divisible by `b`.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. Whatever `test` and `test2` actually turn out to be, they'll always be that type, no matter what, in perpetuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do i compare types in c++?

In your given example, you can use `decltype` along with `std::is_same` to check if `test` is the same as `int` and `test2` is the same as `int` as shown below:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(test), int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(test2), int>);
```